# location hash without the #

Tags: javascript, html

How to make this thing, i want when giving a location.hash, to output in the addres bar like this, for example..

I have

```
location.hash = "asd";
```

And it will output **#asd**

But how to make to output only **asd**

Comment: Well it wouldn't be a hash without the `#` part. You should just use `.href`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the URL using JavaScript without actually loading a new page, you need to use the HTML5 history API and its pushState method.

- http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html
- http://html5demos.com/history
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#section_4

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
location.href
```

Comment: its reloading the page, and i dont need that